# py2exe and numpy not getting along

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, py2exe

I am trying to use py2exe-0.6.9.win32 to wrap up an application that I have written in Python2.6.5 using the following object libraries with associated download file names:

matplotlib-0.99.3.win32

[numpy-1.4.1-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.4.1/)

scipy-0.8.0b1-win32

wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.11.0

I am getting error messages when I try to launch the resulting .exe file.  At the moment, the error message is related to numpy, though before that I was getting something related to matplot lib data files not loading and thus blocking the launch of my exe file.

Rather than post a mile of code and all the error messages, I am posting a more general question: **Can anyone show me some instructions for making all of these object libraries and versions play well together using py2exe to create a working exe file?**

I have been reading things that come up with google searches on the topic, but it seems like a wild goose chase in that everyone is using different versions of different things.  I can change some of the versions of some of these object libraries if that makes a difference, but I have already written 5,000 lines of code in this signal processing application, and I would prefer not to have to re-write all of it, if possible.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a simplified version of my code in a file called GUIdiagnostics.py that I made to test the ability of my py2exe script to import all the libraries that I need in my real application:

```
import time
import wxversion
import wx
import csv
import os
import pylab as p
from scipy import stats
import math
from matplotlib import *
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import scipy.signal as signal
import scipy.optimize
import Tkinter

ID_EXIT = 130

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,wx.ID_ANY,title, size = (500,500), style =     wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Click Here", pos=(160, 120))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick,self.button)

        # the combobox Control
        self.sampleList = ['first','second','third']
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self, label="Choose TestID to filter:", pos=(20, 75))
        self.edithear = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(160, 75), size=(95, -1),     choices=self.sampleList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        # the progress bar
        self.progressMax = 3
        self.count = 0
        self.newStep='step '+str(self.count)
        self.dialog = None

        #-------Setting up the menu.
        # create a new instance of the wx.Menu() object
        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        # enables user to exit the program gracefully
        filemenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate the program")

        #------- Creating the menu.
        # create a new instance of the wx.MenuBar() object
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        # add our filemenu as the first thing on this menu bar
        menubar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        # set the menubar we just created as the MenuBar for this frame
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        #----- Setting menu event handler
        wx.EVT_MENU(self,ID_EXIT,self.OnExit)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnExit(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        try:
            if not self.dialog:
                self.dialog = wx.ProgressDialog("Progress in processing your data.", self.newStep,
                                            self.progressMax,
                                            style=wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                            | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                            | wx.PD_SMOOTH)
            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Start'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)
            TestID = self.edithear.GetValue()

            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Continue.'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)
            myObject=myClass(TestID)
            print myObject.description

            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Finished.'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)

            self.count = 0

            self.dialog.Destroy()

        except:
            self.dialog.Destroy()
            import sys, traceback
            xc = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
            d = wx.MessageDialog( self, ''.join(xc),"Error",wx.OK)
            d.ShowModal() # Show it
            d.Destroy() #finally destroy it when finished

class myClass():
    def __init__(self,TestID):
        self.description = 'The variable name is:  '+str(TestID)+'. '

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None,-1,"My GUI")
app.MainLoop()
```

Here is the code for setup.py, which is the file containing my py2exe code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# Remove the build folder, a bit slower but ensures that build contains the latest
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("build", ignore_errors=True)

# my setup.py is based on one generated with gui2exe, so data_files is done a bit differently
data_files = []
includes = []
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'pywin.debugger',
        'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
        'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'pydoc', 'doctest', 'test', 'sqlite3'
        ]
packages = ['pytz']
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
            'tk84.dll']
icon_resources = []
bitmap_resources = []
other_resources = []

# add the mpl mpl-data folder and rc file
import matplotlib as mpl
data_files += mpl.get_py2exe_datafiles()

setup(
    windows=['GUIdiagnostics.py'],
                      # compressed and optimize reduce the size
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2, 
                      "optimize": 2,
                      "includes": includes,
                      "excludes": excludes,
                      "packages": packages,
                      "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                      # using 2 to reduce number of files in dist folder
                      # using 1 is not recommended as it often does not work
                      "bundle_files": 2,
                      "dist_dir": 'dist',
                      "xref": False,
                      "skip_archive": False,
                      "ascii": False,
                      "custom_boot_script": '',
                     }
          },

    # using zipfile to reduce number of files in dist
    zipfile = r'lib\library.zip',

    data_files=data_files
)
```

I run this code by typing the following line into the command line interface of windows (cmd.exe) as per the following link:

```
setup.py py2exe
```

Py2exe then runs, but when I try to launch the resulting exe file, it creates a log file containing the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pylab.pyo", line 1, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\pylab.pyo", line 206, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\mpl.pyo", line 3, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\axes.pyo", line 14, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\collections.pyo", line 21, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\backend_bases.pyo", line 32, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\widgets.pyo", line 12, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "matplotlib\mlab.pyo", line 388, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'dict'
```

**Can anyone show me how to edit setup.py so that py2exe can create a usable executable running numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.?**

---

**SECOND EDIT:**

OK.  I tried RC's advice again today now that I have a fresh mind for this, and I got the same errorr, but I am including it below.  Here is the code for a file called cxsetup.py that I created following the template at: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html .

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
        name = "Potark",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My application.",
        executables = [Executable("Potark-ICG.py")])
```

Unfortunately, running it in the command line ( cmd.exe ) with the command:

```
python cxsetup.py build
```

generates the following error in the command line:

```
ImportError: No module named cx_Freeze
```

The directory in the command line is the directory for my application, which is in a subfolder of the desktop.  That is different than the directory for the python application, but I assume cmd.exe can figure that out because python can figure it out.  **Am I wrong?**  As a test, I added the following line of code to the first line of cxsetup.py :

```
import matplotlib
```

But that generated the almost identical error:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

I have tried to keep this thread focused and short, but it is getting kind of long.  **Can anyone help me with this?**  I would hate to do all the work of switching to cx_freeze only to find that it cannot work with numpy, matplotlib, scipy, etc.

Comment: perhaps you could try with cxfreeze and see if it helps creating a working exe

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that, but I am getting a different error message from cxfreeze and I would prefer to keep this thread focused so that I do not confuse people with too much code or too many error messages. This aspect of programming is new to me.

Comment: No problem, it was just worth trying.

Comment: I tried your advice again today and got the error message described in my second edit above.  I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: I do not mean to confuse anyone for switching to cx_freeze.  I am just as happy to do it in py2exe.  I just want something that works with numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc as described above.  I have a feeling this can get hairy if someone does not suggest a simple solution.  And I am afraid that it would be just as messy with cx_freeze as it would be with py2exe.  Unless someone who knows and who spends a little time with it can give a straightforward summary of the solution.  ALL of my relevant code is above.

Comment: Have you tried with "bundle_files": 3 ? The error message makes me think that the problem is with bundling, so trying that might give some more clues.

You could also try with "skip_archive": True.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that.  I have also been trying other things and getting other error messages.  This thread is getting way too long for anyone to read, so I am going to close this out and consider how to re-frame the problem in more concise terms, given what I have learned so far.  If I re-post the re-framed question on this forum, I will include a link to this longer, original posting.  Thank you again.

Comment: Maybe no optimization may fix it. I have an app which uses matplotlib 1.0.0, numpy 1.6.1, scipy 0.10.0, wx 2.8.12.1.  I can successfully freeze it using py2exe (on GUI2Exe) with optimize=0, compressed=2, Bundle Files=1.  But, with optimize=1 or 2, I get an error similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem mentioned on the bottom of this: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

Looks like you need to make a few small changes to mlab.py:

```
psd.__doc__ = psd.__doc__ % kwdocd
```

to

```
if psd.__doc__ is not None:
    psd.__doc__ = psd.__doc__ % kwdocd
else:
    psd.__doc__ = ""
```

If you haven't seen this page already this is how I got there: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, py2exe seems to require ugly, random fixes on a case-by-case basis... there appears to be no way around it. Also, some errors refuse to go away, and do not impact the program, but do cause the program to inform the user that an errors log was created after exit. To avoid that, I use this code:

```
import sys
IS_USING_PY2EXE = hasattr(sys, "frozen")

# Redirect output to a file if this program is compiled.     
if IS_USING_PY2EXE:
    # Redirect log to a file.
    LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(logDir, "myfile.log")
    print('Redirecting Stderr... to %s' % LOG_FILENAME)
    logFile = open(os.path.join(LOG_FILENAME),"w") # a --> append, "w" --> write

    sys.stderr = logFile
    sys.stdout = logFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might just me being stupid, but why dont you try to update your scipy from 0.8.0b1 to 0.8.0 and do the same with matplotlib? Numpy 1.4.1 should still be fine.